# Copy template sheet multiple time with button

Tags: vba, excel

On My template I would like to click a button that asks me how many times I would like to generate a copy of it and then generate the copies.

I'm trying the following:

```
Sheets.add after=activeSheet
```

or

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe this is what your trying to do?*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Num%
    Dim i%

    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Num = Application.InputBox("Enter a Number", Type:=1)

    For i = 1 To Num
        Sht.Copy after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = i
    Next i

End Sub
```

*Right click on your ActiveX controls button and paste the code*

***[Application.InputBox Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx)***

> *<sub>Displays a dialog box for user input. Returns the information entered in the dialog box.
>
>   values that can be passed in the Type argument Can be one or a sum of the values. 
>
>   For example, for an input box that can accept both text and numbers, **`set Type to 1 + 2.`**</sub>*

```
+-------+-------------------------------------+
| Value |               Meaning               |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|     0 | A formula                           |
|     1 | A number                            |
|     2 | Text (a string)                     |
|     4 | A logical value (True or False)     |
|     8 | A cell reference, as a Range object |
|    16 | An error value, such as #N/A        |
|    64 | An array of values                  |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure maybe. Do I copy and paste this in an 'active control' button?